# Batch script which automatically executes silent installs (errors out back to cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

```
@echo off

Setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion
REM %%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
REM %%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
REM %%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
REM %%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
cls
set "var="
set /a total=0

set setupLocation=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\setup\
set installer=*.lnk


for %%s in ("%setupLocation%%installer%") do (
    set /a total+=1
) 

echo.
echo  %total% Programs to be installed:
echo.
set /a count=0

for %%I in ("%setupLocation%%installer%") do (

set currentInstall=%%~nI
echo %currentInstall% 

        for %%s in ("%setupLocation%*.exe") do (
        SET var=%%s
        SET var|FINDSTR /b "var="|FINDSTR /i %currentInstall% >nul
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo.>nul) ELSE (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo %%s') do set Program[%count%]=%%~nI )

        ) 

        for %%s in ("%setupLocation%*.lnk") do (
            SET var=%%s
            SET var|FINDSTR /b "var="|FINDSTR /i %currentInstall% >nul
            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo.>nul) ELSE (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo %%s') do set File[%count%]=%%i )
            echo !File[%count%]!

        ) 


        for %%s in ("%setupLocation%*.loc") do (
            SET var=%%s
            SET var|FINDSTR /b "var="|FINDSTR /i %currentInstall% >nul
            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo.>nul) ELSE (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %%s') do set Dir[%count%]=%%i )
            echo !Dir[%count%]!

        ) 
set /a count=%count%+1
echo %count%

) 
echo.
pause




for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set Program[') do (
echo %%s
set /a counter+=1
)

echo test %counter%



:loop
cls

if %counter% EQU 0 goto end


for /l %%n in (0,1,%counter%) do (
    if exist !Dir[%%n]! (
        echo !File[%%n]! Already Installed.
        SET /A counter=%counter%-1
        pause
        if %counter% EQU 0 goto end
        echo %counter%
    ) else (

        echo.
        echo Installing !Program[%%n]! & echo.
        echo ******************************************************************************* & echo.

        echo   Install Location: !Dir[%%n]! & echo.
        echo     Setup Location: !File[%%n]! & echo.

        start "" /w /b !File[%%n]! 

    )
    SET /A counter=%counter%-1
    echo %counter% Programs to be installed.
)   


    goto loop

:end    
echo Everything already installed.
pause
```

it would check the root folder C:\setup\ for 3 files, being:

```
nmap.lnk
nmap.exe
nmap.loc

wireshark.lnk
wireshark.exe
wireshark.loc
```

(containing the default install dir of wireshark used to check whether the program is already present in the program files dir.)

im using this as a base to slipstream a larger amount of programs into custom windows images, rather than getting the registry for each program.

the main issue being it errors back to cmd, i had issues where arithmetic wasnt applying, as i subtracted from the var, the next echo did not reflect that.

if anyone has an alternative solution to the loop used in the  install section that would be appreciated.

and the ink would have the /s silent parameters.

i was going to add the option for it too clean up after itself after install too.

Comment: You may need to explain your three files and their purpose. There doesn't seem to be a check if anything is installed just a check for the existence of the name of a .loc file in the current directory.

Comment: You are inside a code block. You need to use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do a similar thing, i.e. check that all three files exist and if the path, *(without trailing backslash)*, written as the first line inside .loc doesn't exist start the associated .lnk file.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "SetUpLocation=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Setup"

PushD "%SetUpLocation%"||Exit/B

ClS
Set "i=0"
For %%s In (*.loc) Do (If Exist "%%~ns.lnk" (If Exist "%%~ns.exe" (
    Set/P IL=<"%%s"
    If Exist "!IL!\" (Echo=Program %%~ns already installed) Else (
        Echo=Installing %%~ns& Echo.
        Echo *******************************************************************************
        Echo.& Echo   Install Location : !IL!& Echo.
        Echo   Setup Location   : %SetUpLocation%& Echo.
        (Start "" /W /B "%%~ns.lnk")&&Set/A i+=1))))
Echo.
Echo  %i% Programs were installed:
Echo.

PopD
Timeout/T -1 >Nul
```

I have no idea if the wait will work with a .lnk file since the .exe will be running, not the .lnk, so you may have to put the switches on the second line of the .loc file, do away with the .lnk file then run the .exe directly using the read switches.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "SetUpLocation=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Setup"

PushD "%SetUpLocation%"||Exit/B

ClS
Set "i=0"
For %%s In (*.loc) Do (If Exist "%%~ns.exe" (
    (For %%I In (IL ES) Do (Set "%%I="&Set/P "%%I="))<"%%s"
    If Exist "!IL!\" (Echo=Program %%~ns already installed) Else (
        Echo=Installing %%~ns& Echo.
        Echo *******************************************************************************
        Echo.& Echo   Install Location : !IL!& Echo.
        Echo   Setup Location   : %SetUpLocation%& Echo.
        (Start "" /W /B "%%~ns.exe" !ES!)&&Set/A i+=1)))
Echo.
Echo  %i% Programs were installed:
Echo.

PopD
Timeout/T -1 >Nul
```

Comment: Also thanks again, i had done a little research on the pushD command, and that seems to be why i was crashing to cmd, with that it allows me to work in other directories and still keep running my batch file, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Yes the example you had provided works perfect!, does exactly what i needed.

Much prefer your code too. I had a lot of redundant lines, and am more accustomed to passing to variables to improve the readers understanding.

For this use though, this would be fine.

Ill likely leave out the option to check for matching files, I did that just for extra functionality.

and from the looks of it, using a .lnk with start works,

if anyone is wondering the use of this program still, it to mitigate the efforts needed when creating a custom image on windows, so you can auto install software after you install a new os:

rather than grabbing the reg keys, start menu icons, drivers, etc.

and adding them all together in a .wa or other for programs like win toolkit.

More so just comparing the two options, for some software, like this.

Comment: Could you please therefore mark my answer as correct such that future visitors can potentially benefit.